# if statement conditions are embedded in a column

Tags: if-statement, sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS table that has the if condition embedded in the condition1 column of that table. To be more explicit, I created a test dataset:

```
data test;
infile datalines delimiter=','; 
input x1 x2 flag $ condition1 $ value_cond1_true $ value_cond1_false $ ;
datalines;                      
1,5, ,x1>x2,A,B
6,5, ,x2>x1,D,A
3,2, , ,C,D
;
run;
```

I am wondering if it possible to create a code that can directly output in the SAS code the if statement  instead of creating a single macro-variable for each observation `(&cond1_1, &cond1_2, ... &cond1_n)`.

Here is what I would want to do (I know it is not possible to use call symput in that case):

```
data final;
set test;
/* For each observation */
do i=1 to _n_;
/* Creating macro-variables for the if condition */
call symput("cond1",CONDITION1);
call symput("value_cond1_true",VALUE_COND1_TRUE);
call symput("value_cond1_false",VALUE_COND1_FALSE);
/* If the cond1 macro-variable is not empty then do */
if %sysevalf(%superq(cond1)=, boolean) = 0 then do;
    if &cond1. then flag = &value_cond1_true.;
        else flag = &value_cond1_false.;
    end;
/* If the cond1 macro-variable is empty then */
else flag = "X";
end;
run;
```

Comment: Figure out what code you want to generate first then we can show you how to generate that code from your input data.  Show what code you would like to run for the example input.  Show what output you would want from that code.

Comment: Why is there a case (row 3) that has `condition1` missing ?

Comment: @Richard it could be that the condition1 is missing and so you will just put "X" for the flag. This is what I meant with the last else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data can not modify the statements of a running DATA Step.

There is no 'dynamic expression resolver' that is part of data step.

There are some options though

- Use the data to write source code

  - A different conditional has to be performed for each row (*n*)
- Use `resolve()` to dynamically evaluate an expression in the macro system.

  - The values of the variables have to be replaced into the conditional for each row (*n*)

**Write a program**

```
filename evals temp;

data _null_;
  file evals;
  set test;

  length statement $256;

  put 'if _n_ = ' _n_ ' then do;';

  if missing(condition1) then 
    statement = 'flag="X";'; /* 'call missing(flag);'; */
  else
    statement = 'flag = ifc(' 
    || trim(condition1) || ',' 
    || quote(trim(value_cond1_true )) || ','
    || quote(trim(value_cond1_false ))
    || ');';

  put statement;
  put 'end;';
run;

options source2;

data want;
  set test;
  length flag $8;
  %include evals;
  keep x1 x2 flag;
run;

filename evals;
```

**`RESOLVE` function**

```
data want;
  set test;

  length flag $8 cond expr $256;

  cond = condition1;
  cond = transtrn(cond,'x1',cats(x1));
  cond = transtrn(cond,'x2',cats(x2));

  expr = 'ifc(' || trim(cond) || ',' || 
           trim(value_cond1_true) || ',' || 
           trim(value_cond1_false) ||
         ')';

  if not missing (condition1) then 
    flag = resolve ('%sysfunc(' || trim(expr) || ')');
  else
    flag = "X";

  keep x1 x2 flag;
run;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. You are even providing several options. Thank you so much @Richard

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the data to write code then take advantage of the power of the PUT statement.

```
data have;
  infile cards dsd truncover;
  input x1 x2 condition1 $ value_cond1_true $ value_cond1_false $ ;
cards;                      
1,5,x1>x2,A,B
6,5,x2>x1,D,A
3,2,,C,D
;

filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set have;
  file code;
  if condition1 ne ' ';
  put
    'if _n_=' _n_ 'then flag=ifc(' condition1
    ',' value_cond1_true :$quote.
    ',' value_cond1_false :$quote.
    ');'
  ;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  length flag $8 ;
  flag='X';
  %include code / source2;
run;
```

Results:

```
84    data want;
85      set have;
86      length flag $8 ;
87      flag='X';
88      %include code / source2;
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file CODE is file ...\#LN00059.
89   +if _n_=1 then flag=ifc(x1>x2 ,"A" ,"B" );
90   +if _n_=2 then flag=ifc(x2>x1 ,"D" ,"A" );
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) ending.
91    run;

NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 3 observations and 6 variables.
```